# How can I assign to an instance variable in C++ when a local variable has same name?

Tags: c++, instance-variables

I have a class defined like this:

```
class MyClass 
{
    int x;
    public: 
        MyClass(int x); 
};

MyClass::MyClass(int x)
{ //Assign x here 
}
```

However, I can't initialize `x` in the constructor because it has the same name as an instance variable. Is there any way around this(other than changing the name of the argument)?

Comment: You are making an error. The compiler rightfully complains. Fix your code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best option is to use the constructor's initializer list:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x) : x( x ) { // Body }
```

But you could also try this approach:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x) { this->x = x; }
```

Comment: @dirkgently GCC 4.2 doesn't complain about this... any reason that shadowing is bad?

Comment: @dirkgently -- shadowing might not be ideal, but it's valid C++. We could debate shadowing all day long, but what he wanted to know was C++ semantics.

Comment: Seriously. You could not advice him to use a better name

Answer (score 10):

> However, I can't initialize x in the constructor because it has the same name as an instance variable. Is there any way around this(other than changing the name of the argument)?

So change the name of the parameter!

```
class MyClass  
{ 
    int x; 
    public:  
        MyClass(int xInitVal);  
}; 

MyClass::MyClass(int xInitVal)
    :x(xInitVal)
{ // Don't assign x here.  
}
```

By making the parameter name the same as a local you are just making the code hard to read.

Don't do it. Nearly every style guide you  come across will tell you not to make parameters the same name as members.

Answer (score 3):

as an aside - you really should have a naming convention for your member variables that does not clash. This is usually coding rules 1 or 2 for c++ houses. Then when you see m_foo = bar you know exactly what is going on

we use

```
 int m_thingy;
```

I have also seen

```
 int _thingy;
 int thingy_
```

apologies in advance if you knew this and could not or would not do it

Comment: Best to avoid identifiers that start with "_".

Comment: Ditto to Bill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Answer (score 2):

`this->x = x;`

Comment: Seriously. You could not advice him to use a better name. And for more complex types that are not int this is the wrong answer anyway.

Comment: Yeh, you are right. Better names, no extra initialization, etc. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` to explicitly refer to the current object:

```
this->x = x;
```

Comment: Seriously. You could not advice him to use a better name. And for more complex types that are not int this is the wrong answer anyway.

Comment: How come that people with higher rep are laconically suggesting `this->x = x;` while people with lower rep are suggesting to rename the parameter? Superior technical knowledge vs common sense? :)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you just change the variable names. Messing with duplicate identifiers is a fight without a cause.

In my code, I give all function parameters the prefix 'in' ("inValue"). I give all private member variables the prefix 'm' ("mValue").

Answer (score 0):

Use `this->x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the this pointer

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x)
{
    this->x = x;
}
```

Of course not having colliding names like that in the first place would be a better solution.

Comment: I guess this combines the worst of both worlds.  There is no need for `this->x = x`, which is poor form.  Also, as *Scott Meyers* states in his **Effective C++** series, "Prefer initialization lists in constructors."

Answer (score 0):

this->x = x isn't working?  That's what we did (or used a different parameter name).